# Pdfcreator print file to multiple images (.png)

Tags: images, png

I am using [pdfcreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator). It installs a virtual windows printer that saves the file being printed into the desired format. I want to save my printed documents as multiple image files. (`.png`). I configured the auto save option in pdf creator to automatically save in `.png` format when a file is sent to the pdfcreator printer. My problem is that only the first page gets saved to the png file. I want it to print all pages , one image for each page. Is that possible?

Comment: I've had similar issue trying to save as .bmp

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting for this behaviour.
Just tick the option "One file per document (not for PDF and EPS files)" under Settings -> Application -> Document.

Answer (score 0):

Now in Version 1.6 and 1.7 of PDFcreator the Option `One file per document (not for PDF and EPS files)` is under `Printer` -> `Options` -> `Document` -> `Document Properties 2 (Tab)` -> `One File Per Page (Panel)`.